# Android VR video in Webview using Google Cardboard to play/pause

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, google-cardboard

I have been using Google Cardboard API to playing VR video on Android.

Video playing is done well. But, can't control play and pause.

Here my source codes.

It's android Activity source code.

```
public class RecodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     public String VideoUrl;
     public String file;
     public WebView webView;
     private boolean isStart = false;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_recode);
         file= getIntent().getStringExtra("file");
         VideoUrl = "****";    //url



         webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
         webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
         webView.loadUrl(VideoUrl);

         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
         webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
 }
```

And, This is HTML Source Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>And, This is HTML Source Code </title>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style>
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen src="../../index.html?image=examples/pano/andes_2048.jpg&is_stereo=true&preview=examples/pano/andes_512.jpg"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Implementation of the src attribute of the iframe tags had been coded as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>VR view</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="error" class="dialog">
            <div class="wrap">
                <h1 class="title">Error</h1>
                <p class="message">An unknown error occurred.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a id="watermark" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/ic_info_outline_black_24dp.svg"/>
        </a>

        <script src="build/vrview-analytics.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more information about the exact code, in this GitHub.
https://github.com/google/vrview

Can you tell me VR video control is possible and if it can, how to control this.

Please help me! Thanks in advance.